# Scraping a dynamically rendered webpage that replaces content when scrolling with python

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping

A bit of a long winded question, but essentially I'm looking for a way/few tips in scraping data off a website which dynamically loads content when scrolling.

This particular website *removes* content when I scroll down. Essentially, when it stops being visible it's no longer in the DOM, and I'm unable to scrape anything from it.

Currently I'm using Selenium to try and get somewhere but to no avail. I have no idea where to even begin with something like this.

I'm thinking about scrolling to a point where the top div becomes hidden, scraping, then rinse and repeat all the way down. I don't think that's efficient at all and surely there's a better way.

Comment: Maybe you could take a look at your network traffic and see what calls it is making to the API to get new content. You could possibly make the calls yourself

Comment: I thought about this actually, are you able to point me to a similar question/guide for this sort of stuff?

Comment: Not sure about a guide but when I do this I use [chrome dev tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools), go to the network tab, clear it, then execute the action that triggers the fetch. Then I try to work out their url structure and requirements to make requests. Ex. `page/1` can be easily automated to get page `n`. You can use python's [requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to make them.

Comment: Thanks mate, very helpful